# Why is iPhone 8 screen size reported as 320x480?

Tags: ios, screen, aspect-ratio

I have inherited an app that uses separate Storyboards for iPhone and iPad. Neither uses autolayout. In `viewDidLoad()` I log the value of `UIScreen.main.bounds`.

For *any* iPhone (5s through X) the logged size is 320x480. This does not change after `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

When I create an app from scratch, I get the expected sizes (e.g. 375x667 for iPhone 6 thru 8).

What could be different in my hand-me-down app that makes the screen size uniformly the ancient values for 1x iPhones?

Please note this has nothing to do with *view* resizing -- this is the *screen* we are talking about. Similarly the screen scale plays no apparent role.

Comment: The "Default" image or launch image is not the correct sizes..

Comment: Wow, you are the man! The project doesn't use a Launch Storyboard (as would a "modern" project) and the launch image in Images.xcassets is... 640x960, i.e. 320x480 * screen scale. Thank you!

Comment: @Brandon, you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new project, if it comes with a Storyboard for Launch images, the size will be automatically detected..

However, for older projects that uses Image Assets instead, you need to provide sizes for the launch screen. IE: "Default" images of the correct sizes of the screen as per:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Static Launch Screen Images. The names shall be: "Default-XXXh@ResY.png"

where XXX is the height and Y is the resolution.. Example:

- iPhone 6 Plus - 1242px x 2208px - Default-736h@3x.png
- iPhone 6 - 750px x 1334px - Default-667h@2x.png